# I try to insert select tag data with multiple category

Tags: laravel

```
Error :- **Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() cannot be called statically**
 Error :- **Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() cannot be called statically**
```

Error :- **Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() cannot be called statically**
Error :- **Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() cannot be called statically**

```
**Post Controller**
 

 public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required|min:5|max:255',
            'content' => 'required|min:5',
            'image' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required'
        ]);
        $newimagename = time() . '-' . $request->name . '.' . $request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('img') , $newimagename);
        $post_obj = new Post;
        $post_obj->post_name=$request->title;
        $post_obj->post_content=$request->content;
         $post_obj->file_path = $newimagename;
        $post_obj->name=$request->name;
        $post_obj->status=$request->status;
        $post_obj->cat_id=implode(',', request::get('cat_name'));
        $post_obj->save();
        $request->session()->flash("sucess", "Your Post is saved!");
        return redirect("add-post");
     } 

 **blade.php**

    <select  class="form-control form-control-lg" name="cat_name" multiple="multiple">
        @foreach($category as $cat)
            <option value="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
        <@endforeach
    </select>

When i use to submit select tag data then error is class input not found but i already import the 
input 

$post_obj->cat_id=implode(',', Input::get('cat_name'));

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Input;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\post;
    use App\Models\Cat;
    use Validator;
```

Error :- **Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() cannot be called statically**
Error :- **Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() cannot be called statically**
Error :- **Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() cannot be called statically**
Error :- **Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() cannot be called statically**

Comment: import `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to controller and return `$request->all()` for see params

Comment: try ```$request->input('cat_name')``` instead of ```Input::get('cat_name')``` & ```request::get('cat_name')```